# How explain the function count the number of bits is odd or even

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Found the function on "Computer Systems":

```
int fun_a(unsigned x){
    int val = 0;
    while(x){
        val ^= x;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return val & 0x1;
}
```

it return 1 if x contains odd "1", return 0 if x contains even "1".
I know "val & 0x1" check val is odd or even, but I don't know how it count the bits number on val.

Comment: Use the pen and paper method. Try out with a few numbers.

Comment: For clarity, this really shouldn't be `int val` but `unsigned val`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't exactly count the bits, but the XOR will flip the low bit in `val` once for each bit in `x`. That will make it a `1` if it is flipped an odd number of times.

It also flips a lot of other bits in `val`, but that is irrelevant as they are masked off in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

When doing bit twiddling, you usually want to think not of numbers, but instead of an array of bits. `^` performs addition mod 2 in every bit. Since only the low bit of `val` matters, what is happening to it?

`val` really should be unsigned, though, although most computer architectures won't give you problems. Really, in situations where you're using functions like this, you really should be using the fixed-width integral types, like `uint32_t`.